# Cannot applying find() method with Native MongoDB becaus of ID type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I have a function that is needed to get results.

When I give 1 as _id filter everything is OK.

```
collectionPersonnel
     .find({ '_id' : 1 })
     .toArray(function (err, personnel) {
     console.log(personnel);  
  });
```

If I give filter another way for instance user[0]['personnel_id'] -that is store 1- then I get only [] result;

```
collectionPersonnel
     .find({ '_id' : user[0]['personnel_id'] })
     .toArray(function (err, personnel) {
     console.log(personnel);  
  });
```

And then I've tried another way. But it doesn't work because I used a string(user[0]['personnel_id']) instead of an ObjectID.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; 
var personnelPK_Hex = (user[0]['personnel_id']).toHexString(); 
var personnelPK = ObjectID.createFromHexString(personnelPK_Hex);
```

What should I do?

### Edit

All of my codes are below;

```
module.exports = {

    show: function(req, res) {

        User.native(function(err, collectionUser) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("There is no exist a User by current_id");
            };
            collectionUser
            .find({'_id' : req.param('id')})
            .toArray(function (err, user) {

                Personnel.native(function(err, collectionPersonnel) {
                    if(err) {
                        // handle error getting mongo collection
                        console.log("There is no exist a Personel by current _id");
                    };
                    if(!collectionPersonnel) {
                        console.log("There is no exist a Personel by current _id");
                    };

                    // var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; 
                    // var personnelPK_Hex = (user[0]['personnel_id']).toHexString(); 
                    // var personnelPK = ObjectID.createFromHexString(personnelPK_Hex);                  

                    collectionPersonnel
                    .find({ '_id' : user[0].personnel_id })
                    .toArray(function (err, personnel) {

                        console.log(personnel);   
                    });
                });
            });            
        });
    }
};
```

And console's output is;
[]

### Solved

Just like apsillers's said. I had given a numeric _id to collection, incorrectly.
I've fixed _id value and everything is OK.

Thank you all...

Comment: Exactly! You are right! I've solved problem a short while ago. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @apsillers - go ahead and post your solution as an answer so OP can give you points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user[0]['personnel_id']` might be a string. For Mongo, `"1"` is different from `1`, which is why your literal number `1` worked, but your variable (which holds a string) does not.

Instead, try using a unary plus to convert the string to a number: `+user[0]['personnel_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like **user[0].personal_id** instead of **user[0]['personnel_id']**  please provide your schema design that would be better to figure out what exactly you are missing.

**i tried like this**

```
collectionPersonnel
 .find({ '_id' : user[0].personnel_id })
 .toArray(function (err, personnel) {
 console.log(personnel);  
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, David. I've tried your advice but it doesn't work for me. Meanwhile, when I write user[0].personnel_id or user[0]['personnel_id'] to the console.log, then the console output 1 properly. (I don't know how to provide schema design) I've been trying nested queries. Firstly, to query 'User' collection and secondly to query Personnel collection with 'User.personnel_id' that returned result of my first query. Actually this is a nested query. I'm editing my question. Thank you again.